# Calling EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD) does not change text field to a password field

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` field in my Android app named `password`

When I called `password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)`, the field does not change into a password text field. Why is this and what can I do to make it a password field at runtime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to combine 2 flags:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Check the other examples in the [docs for InputType class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).